# Por que me manda error Cuando Modifico un datos de una Lista

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista

Tengo este código en c# pero al momento que quiero modificar un dato por medio de su posición e imprimir el dato modificado me marca erro

Ejemplo:

Ingreso los siguientes Datos:

Nombre:Fernando Perez

Telefono:1234

Este dato se guardo en la posición `0` y al momento de que quiero modificar el dato por medio se su posicion manda lanza esta excepción:

> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e
>   inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index

```
List<List<string>> Matriz = new List<List<string>>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioGuardar.Checked == true)
        {
            List<string> registro = new List<string>();

            registro.Add(textBoxNom.Text);
            registro.Add(textBoxtel.Text);
            Matriz.Add(registro);

            MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");
        }

          string caja = "";

        if (radioImprimir.Checked == true)
        {          
            foreach (var item in Matriz)
            {
                caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]+ "\n");

            }
            MessageBox.Show(caja);
           }

        if (radio_Modificar.Checked == true)
        {
            List<string> registro = new List<string>();

            for(int i = 0; i < registro.Count; i++)
            {
                int pos = int.Parse(txtBuscar.Text);
                Matriz.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(txtBuscar.Text));
                registro.Insert(pos, textBoxNom.Text);
                registro.Insert(pos, textBoxApp.Text);
                registro.Insert(pos, textBoxApm.Text);
                registro.Insert(pos, textBoxtel.Text);
            }

            Matriz.Add(registro);
        }
```

Comment: En que linea se dispara esa excepción?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal en la 58 donde esta  caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]+ "\n");

Comment: de dodne sale el "App" y el "Apm" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a darte una solucion mucho mas `orientada a objetos`, asi no complicas el codigo con listas de listas.

Primero crea una clase

```
public class Registro
{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string Telefono {get;set;}
    public string App {get;set;}
    public string Apm {get;set;}
}
```

Y despues usa esta para generar los registros

```
List<Registro> Matriz = new List<Registro>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioGuardar.Checked == true)
    {

        Registro registro = new Registro();

        registro.Nombre = textBoxNom.Text;
        registro.Telefono = textBoxtel.Text;
        registro.App = textBoxApp.Text;
        registro.Apm = textBoxApm.Text;

        Matriz.Add(registro);

        MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados");


    }


    if (radioImprimir.Checked == true)
    {
        string caja = "";
        foreach (var item in Matriz)
        {
            caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}\n", item.Nombre, item.App, item.Apm, item.Telefono);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(caja);
    }

    if (radio_Modificar.Checked == true)
    {
        int pos = int.Parse(txtBuscar.Text);
        if(Matriz.Count > pos) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no se encontro la posicion en la lista");
            return;
        }

        Registro registro = new Registro();
        registro.Nombre = textBoxNom.Text;
        registro.Telefono = textBoxtel.Text;
        registro.App = textBoxApp.Text;
        registro.Apm = textBoxApm.Text;

        Matriz[pos] = registro;

    }
```

Veras que la posicion es sobre la matriz que tiene las entidades con los datos

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema, se da debido a que en el `foreach`

```
foreach (var item in Matriz)
{
    caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]+ "\n");
}
```

Estas accediendo al índice `2` y `3` que no existen.

Al momento de crear y llenar la lista `registro`

```
List<string> registro = new List<string>();
registro.Add(textBoxNom.Text);
registro.Add(textBoxtel.Text);
Matriz.Add(registro);
```

Estas agregando `textBoxNom.Text` y `textBoxtel.Text`

Por lo que, volviendo al `foreach`..

`item[0]` vale lo mismo que `textBoxNom.Text` e `item[1]` vale `textBoxtel.Text`, pero no has agregado más elementos, por lo que `item[2]` e `item[3]` van a disparar una excepción de tipo [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).