# Que hace esta línea de código escrito en c#?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var item in Matriz)
{
    caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}", item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]+ "\n");
}
```

Específicamente no entiendo que hacen las llaves {}

Comment: [foreach en c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: una duda, porque el fragmento de codigo se relaciona con esta otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253451/por-que-me-manda-erro-cuando-modifico-un-datos-de-una-lista, pero con usuarios diferentes?

Comment: a que llaves haces referencia? a las del `for` o a las del `string.Format()`

Comment: Ya que el código lo saque de esa pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hace esta linea es parecido que System.out.printf(); en java.
Entonces, el atributo `item`es un array de 4 posiciones.

item[0] => es la posición 0 de item en sera `Nombre: {0}`

item[1] => es la posición 1 de item en sera `App: {1}`

item[2] => es la posición 2 de item en sera `Apm: {2}`

item[3] => es la posición 3 de item en sera `tel: {3}`

Y como es un foreach, puede rellenar un String (en este caso `caja`), de un array de Matriz. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria leer la documentacion

[string.Format(String, Object[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___)

si lo hicieras verias que al tener un array no necesitas definir cada posicion, podrias haber usado

```
caja += string.Format("Nombre: {0} App: {1} Apm: {2} tel: {3}\n", item);
```

ya que al usar `{x}` estas indicando una posicion en la lista de items que asignas por parametro